# IndexError: list index out of range in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Imported the need packages and models are below,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
```

In this section I just want to check GPU is perfectly working or not But I find an error to check and the checking code is,

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Below the error,

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1fc9c14b9ae0> in <module>()
      1 physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
      2 print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
----> 3 tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Need the help for sloving this issue or please help to install `GPU` in google colab.

Comment: You can simpy use gpu by going to runtime-change runtime- and select gpu. By default the runtime is cpu

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to get the details on the GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device Details: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install Tensorflow that supports GPU")
```

Comment: the commonad "pip install tensorflow " is used for installing GPU and CPU version of tensorflow. Is there any way to check GPU is installed or not??

Comment: I run your code and it's output is "Please install Tensorflow that supports GPU". May be tensorflow GPU version is not installed. how should I install GPU version of tensorflow??

Comment: I install GPU version newly to use "pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15" this command but still now it show the same error which I noticed the questions section